# Is it possible to create a web server like dataplicity.com or weaved for accessing port 80?

Tags: pi-3, remote, port-forwarding

I am working in a project with PI i have to access port 80 remotely on browser, i tried dataplicity.com and weaved to do so, but for security reasons i cant use a third party server and put valuable coding in it? i have searched in many sources and didn't found any positive results, is there any way to create it so i can access my 80 port without port forwarding or static IP?

Any help will be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Unless you are well versed in OS hardening, security and secure coding. I doubt your homegrown solution will provide any more security than the 3rd party apps. Second if the data is that sensitive it calls into question using a Pi in the first place (physical security, default usernames and passwords among other things make it less than idea for security purposes).

Comment: you may right, but i don't have any other choice, my project concept is, accessing the machine with the help of RPi, in field machine wont get public IP everywhere, even if the RPi may be connected with a mobile hotspot, in such case how to access it?

Comment: Have you considered reversing the communication why not have the Pi call home with the info you need. No need for a static IP on the Pi.

Comment: thank you so much for this help, i am very beginner for this, i tried sending the public ip of the device connected to the Pi to the Server. but no luck i cant do anything, if reverse communication is possible how to do it..? just give me some hints

Comment: Have you considered cellular communication ?

Comment: no, is there any tutorials to use it?

Answer (score 1):

One way to make your RPi accessible from anywhere is to get yourself a public IP address from your Internet provider. You might need to pay for it, or it may be a free service.

Then, depending on your network setup, you can just assign the public IP to your RPi, or forward port 80 of the RPi to the public IP inside your local network.

Comment: i agree but, how dataplicity.com and remot3 it works without it? form their server?

Comment: Yes, they certainly have public IP addresses of their own. They let you use those IPs to connect, then channel the traffic to your device. It is true that this is as secure as trusting a third party could be. Especially for port 80, they get to see all the data you send and receive. SSH may be somewhat more secure, but I can't say that for sure.

Comment: Thank you for making it clear, i have a server with static ip, is it possible to use the server as they do and connect the RPi?

Comment: Whenever the IP is static doesn't matter. You need **public** IP, i.e. one outside of 10.X.Y.Z and 192.168.X.Z subnets.

Comment: ya i own it.. now i have hosted another web application in it and accessing it world wide.